# How can i make a text entry submission be used to make another function?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

So basically i want to make this GUI where you can insert text and then hit the go button ad it would do the feature. (example: "Stopwatch" and then after you hit enter it would start a stopwatch).

```
import tkinter as tk
import math
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Exit", command = root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)

main_entry = root.Entry(root, )




root.mainloop()
```

So basically I want the answer in main entry to be taken and do the action asked in the text insertion.

Comment: You would need to use whitelisting first. Then its just a matter of creating the required functions and using `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 0):

Here i wrote an example on how to use the Entry and the Button widgets in Tkitner:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
import random


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        self.title('Get a random integer')
        self.geometry('400x250')

        Label(self, text='Get a random number from A to B').pack(pady=20)

        self.a_value = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.a_value.insert(END, 'A')
        self.a_value.pack(pady=5)

        self.b_value = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.b_value.insert(END, 'B')
        self.b_value.pack(pady=5)

        self.btn = Button(self, text='Get Random', command=self.get_rand)
        self.btn.pack(pady=5)

        self.out_label = Label(self)
        self.out_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.bind('<Return>', self.get_rand)

    def get_rand(self, event=None):
        a = self.a_value.get()
        b = self.b_value.get()

        try:
            a = int(a)
            b = int(b)

            self.out_label.configure(text=f'{random.randint(a, b)}')

            self.update()

        except Exception as error:
            showerror(title='ERROR', message=f'{error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp = App()
    myapp.mainloop()
```